# Did the Romans divide plays into acts and what did they call them?

Tags: roman-culture

In a previous question it was asked [what the acts were called in Greek plays](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15592/act-1-act-2-in-a-play-in-greek/15594#15594). Did the Romans also divide their plays into specific parts, and what did they call them in Latin?

Comment: I believe they did, and they called them *actus*. And I believe five was already common. L&S: *Hence, also, a larger division of a play, an act: "primo actu placeo", Ter. Hec. prol. 31; "neque minor quinto, nec sit productior actu Fabula", Hor. A. P. 189* ("and let a play be neither shorter nor longer than the fifth act").